# Flutter: Dynamic Initial Route

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

**Dears,**

I am using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) dart package which allows listeners to get notified on changes to models per se.

I am able to detect the change inside my main app root tree, and also able to change the string value of initial route however my screen is not updating. Kindly see below the code snippet and the comments lines:

```
  void main() => runApp(_MyAppMain());

    class _MyAppMain extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>.value(
              value: UserProvider(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<PhoneProvider>.value(
              value: PhoneProvider(),
            )
          ],
          child: Consumer<UserProvider>(
            builder: (BuildContext context, userProvider, _) {
              return FutureBuilder(
                future: userProvider.getUser(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }

                  final User user = snapshot.data;

                  String initialScreen = LoginScreen.path;

    // (1) I am able to get into the condition

                  if (user.hasActiveLogin()) {
                    initialScreen = HomeOneScreen.path;
                  }

                  return MaterialApp(
                    title: 'MyApp',
                    theme: ThemeData(
                      primarySwatch: Colors.green,
                      accentColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                    initialRoute: initialScreen, 
 // (2) here the screen is not changing...?
                    routes: {
                      '/': (context) => null,
                      LoginScreen.path: (context) => LoginScreen(),
                      RegisterScreen.path: (context) => RegisterScreen(),
                      HomeOneScreen.path: (context) => HomeOneScreen(),
                      HomeTwoScreen.path: (context) => HomeTwoScreen(),
                      RegisterPhoneScreen.path: (context) => RegisterPhoneScreen(),
                      VerifyPhoneScreen.path: (context) => VerifyPhoneScreen(),
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Kindly Note the Below:

```
These are are paths static const strings
LoginScreen.path = "login"
RegisterScreen.path = "/register-screen"
HomeOneScreen.path = "home-one-screen"
HomeTwoScreen.path = "home-two-screen"
RegisterPhoneScreen.path = "/register-phone-screen"
VerifyPhoneScreen.path = "/verify-phone-screen"
```

What I am missing for dynamic `initialRoute` to work?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this issue described on [github issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12454) it is not permissible to have initial route changes. At least this is what I understood. However what I did is that I replaced the `initialRoute` attribute with `home` attr. Thus this change mandates that `initialScreen` becomes a widget var.

The changes is shown below:

```
 void main() => runApp(_MyAppMain());

    class _MyAppMain extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>.value(
              value: UserProvider(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<PhoneProvider>.value(
              value: PhoneProvider(),
            )
          ],
          child: Consumer<UserProvider>(
            builder: (BuildContext context, userProvider, _) {
              return FutureBuilder(
                future: userProvider.getUser(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }

                  final User user = snapshot.data;

// (1) This becomes a widget

                  Widget initialScreen = LoginScreen();



                  if (user.hasActiveLogin()) {
                    initialScreen = HomeOneScreen();
                  }

                  return MaterialApp(
                    title: 'MyApp',
                    theme: ThemeData(
                      primarySwatch: Colors.green,
                      accentColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                    home: initialScreen, 
 // (2) here the initial route becomes home attr.
                    routes: {
                      '/': (context) => null,
                      LoginScreen.path: (context) => LoginScreen(),
                      RegisterScreen.path: (context) => RegisterScreen(),
                      HomeOneScreen.path: (context) => HomeOneScreen(),
                      HomeTwoScreen.path: (context) => HomeTwoScreen(),
                      RegisterPhoneScreen.path: (context) => RegisterPhoneScreen(),
                      VerifyPhoneScreen.path: (context) => VerifyPhoneScreen(),
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Also note on my RegistrationScreen on success api response I did `Navigator.of(context).pop()`

Thanks